# How To Increment Months Using HTML 5 Date Input - Output Results To DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm needing help taking value from HTML5 Date Input and use that to increment months from that date value.

It fails on this line: `var result2 = myDate2.addMonths(1);`

When I remove the function that houses it all, it outputs each increment to the console, but breaks when i wrap in a function so I can create a click event.

Can someone help me solve this? I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this.

I also need to output the data that is logged (ie. result1) to the HTML Divs replacing the text "To Calculate".

Thanks in advance.

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>

    function calculateDate() {

    Date.isLeapYear = function (year) { 
        return (((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0)); 
    };

    Date.getDaysInMonth = function (year, month) {
        return [31, (Date.isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month];
    };

    Date.prototype.isLeapYear = function () { 
        return Date.isLeapYear(this.getFullYear()); 
    };

    Date.prototype.getDaysInMonth = function () { 
        return Date.getDaysInMonth(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth());
    };

    Date.prototype.addMonths = function (value) {
        var n = this.getDate();
        this.setDate(1);
        this.setMonth(this.getMonth() + value);
        this.setDate(Math.min(n, this.getDaysInMonth()));
        return this;
    };


    var myDate = document.getElementById("intro-date").value;
    var result1 = myDate;
    console.log(result1);

    var myDate2 = result1;
    var result2 = myDate2.addMonths(1);
    console.log(result2);

    var myDate3 = result2;
    var result3 = myDate3.addMonths(1);
    console.log(result3);

    var myDate4 = result3;
    var result4 = myDate4.addMonths(1);
    console.log(result4);

    var myDate5 = result4;
    var result5 = myDate5.addMonths(1);
    console.log(result5);

    var myDate6 = result5;
    var result6 = myDate6.addMonths(1);
    console.log(result6);

    var myDate7 = result6;
    var result7 = myDate7.addMonths(1);
    console.log(result7);

    var myDate8 = result7;
    var result8 = myDate8.addMonths(1);
    console.log(result8);

    var myDate9 = result8;
    var result9 = myDate9.addMonths(1);
    console.log(result9);

    var myDate10 = result9;
    var result10 = myDate10.addMonths(1);
    console.log(result10);

    var myDate11 = result10;
    var result11 = myDate11.addMonths(1);
    console.log(result11);

    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="GestationForm">
    <input type="date" id="intro-date">

    Value one: <div id="value-one">Calculated</div>
    <input type="submit" value="click" onclick="calculateDate()">
</form>
<div id="results">
<div id="month1">FIRST MONTH
    <div id="calculate1">To Calculate
    </div>
</div>
<div id="month2">SECOND MONTH
    <div id="calculate2">To Calculate
    </div>
</div>
<div id="month3">THIRD MONTH
    <div id="calculate3">To Calculate
    </div>
</div>
<div id="month4">FOURTH MONTH
        <div id="calculate4">To Calculate
    </div>
</div>
<div id="month5">FIFTH MONTH
        <div id="calculate5">To Calculate
    </div>
</div>
<div id="month6">SIXTH MONTH
            <div id="calculate6">To Calculate
    </div>
</div>
<div id="month7">SEVENTH MONTH
            <div id="calculate7">To Calculate
    </div>
</div>
<div id="month8">EIGHT MONTH
            <div id="calculate8">To Calculate
    </div>
</div>
<div id="month9">NINTH MONTH
            <div id="calculate9">To Calculate
    </div>
</div>
<div id="month10">TENTH MONTH
            <div id="calculate10">To Calculate
    </div>
</div>
<div id="month11">ELEVENTH MONTH
            <div id="calculate11">To Calculate
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `It fails` - could you be more specific?

Comment: one thing to be aware of ... all `myDate*` and `result*` vars will end up being exactly the same value, because they all reference the same Date object

Comment: I use chrome inspector and set breakpoints at each of the var result(x). It passes the first var result1 = myDate; and I see that it loads the date as data. But, when I step through to the next and it gets to var result2 = myDate2.addMonths(1) the process stops and nothing is logged to the console.

Comment: Mystika's answer is probably for you

Comment: If I remove the surrounding function and just log to console alone, it logs all values correctly to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a `addMonths` function to Date class. and.. variable `myDate` is String not Date.

So you need to declare a `myDate` variable as Date.

```
var myDate = new Date(document.getElementById("intro-date").value);
```

edit:

Also you need to change input elements type to `button` from `submit`

```
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="calculateDate()">
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmxd7x1L/1/)**

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. One other quick question. How do i output the values to the DOM to replace the "To Calculate" text? Ive tried the following but get error "Not a function". var output1 = document.getElementById("calculate1").innerHTML(result2);

Comment: @billy_comic Yup, `innerHTML` is not a function. its a property. you can you innerHTML property like `document.getElementById("calculate1").innerHTML = result2`